# No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: java, android, android-layout

R is not generating in my android application package and I *think* it's because i've got an error in a layout file called menu.xml.  I'm using eclipse and I've imported this source code from a non-eclipse project (I think)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

The error occurs on the android:title="@string/help" /> line

My values folder contains a file "strings.xml" though I've tried the renaming thing and that doesn't appear to help.

Yes I'm a noob...and props to whoever wrote this forum software, pretty durned capable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My values folder contains a file "strings.xml"

That's only half the magic. You need a string in there named `help`, which you probably don't have. It could look like this

```
<string name="help">Help</string>
```

*See [String resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) for more details about the file structure*

Comment: Will it not be <string name="title.help">Help!</string>?  Tried it both ways and nothing...of course, that may lead to another question:  When I hit run, it goes straight to "Your project contains errors...please fix, etc".  I've got shedloads of R.whatever errors in the project...the R file isn't being generated and I was thinking that fixing the layout error might allow that to happen.

Comment: If this still persists, try to clean your project after you fixed all errors. Use `Project -> Clean ..` in eclipse. This regenerates all auto-build files, including the R class. Also, the doc doesn't state it but I guess dots in resource names will lead to problems. You would reference that string in code like `R.string.title.help`. This will most likely not work (can't test it right now, my tools decided to go nuts over an update :/)

Comment: Okay...menu.xml error is gone...R still not generating.  I'll start a new thread if I have to on that one...

Comment: Glad I could help. The way it usually works here is that you don't have to thank someone. It's enough to accept the answer that solved the problem for you by clicking the small checkmark below the voting buttons of the answer. See [how does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). That's an implied thanks, along with the message that this question is answered and solved. :)

Comment: I was looking for that button :-)